# custom url with custom post

Tags: plugins, php, url-rewriting

I want to change my custom post URL. I want to remove "**item**" from URL.

With the below code and with custom post type url plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/
my URL is:

Original URL : **`http://mywebsite/wp/item/america/mayer/`**

Want to change it to **`http://mywebsite/wp/america/mayer/`**

Without using `htaccess`.

**WordPress Code**

```
    function aitDirItemPostType() {

        register_post_type( 'ait-dir-item',
            array(
                'labels' => array(
                    'name'          => 'Items',
                    'singular_name' => 'Item',
                    'add_new'       => 'Add new',
                    'add_new_item'  => 'Add new item',
                    'edit_item'     => 'Edit item',
                    'new_item'      => 'New item',
                    'not_found'     => 'No items found',
                    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No items found in Trash',
                    'menu_name'     => 'Items',
                ),
                'description' => 'Manipulating with items',
                'public' => true,
                'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
                'supports' => array(
                    'title',
                    'thumbnail',
                    'author',
                    'editor',
                    'excerpt',
                    'comments',
                ),
                'show_ui' => true,
                'show_in_menu' => true,
                'menu_icon' => AIT_FRAMEWORK_URL . '/CustomTypes/dir-item/dir-item.png',
                'menu_position' => $GLOBALS['aitThemeCustomTypes']['dir-item'],
                'has_archive' => true,
                'query_var' => 'dir-item',
                'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'item'),
                'capability_type' => 'ait-dir-item',
                'map_meta_cap' => true
            )
        );
        aitDirItemTaxonomies();

        flush_rewrite_rules(false);
    }

add_action( 'init', 'aitDirItemPostType');
```

Comment: "item" is the basename for your custom post type. You can change it in this line of code `'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'item'),` but you can't remove it. If you change it, remember you need to flush the rewrite rules afterwards by visiting the permalinks page in the administrative dashboard.

Comment: no this is a theme code.and if i will change according to you then url will use air-dir-item in place of item. so another solution please..

Answer (score 0):

You can omit the "base", by adding

```
rewrite => array(
    slug       => 'item',
    with_front => false,
),
```

Don't forget to flush your rewrite rules after you changed that. The easiest way to do so it to simply visit the "admin > settings > permalinks" page.

If you need to add that to an already registered post type, then take a look at the internals of [`register_post_type()`](http://queryposts.com/function/register_post_type/) and the available hooks and filters in [its source <sup>Link to GitHub</sup>](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.9.1/wp-includes/post.php#L1198): Make use of the [`registered_post_type`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.9.1/wp-includes/post.php#L1362) action which comes with two arguments: `$post_type` and `$args`.

Comment: sorry with your solution my prob not solved. :(
http://support.ait-themes.com/support/topic/65444 and http://support.ait-themes.com/support/topic/6329

Comment: http://support.ait-themes.com/support/topic/5584?slug=item-permalinks#Item_18

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set the `slug` value to an empty string like `''`, deleting `item`.

I think that @kaiser think that `item` is a generic string for the posts, and he suggest to not prepend that string to your custom post type permalink. That's a good idea. But `item` is the slug for the CPT, so that's why is not working